# How can I use AllChars on Windows7 with IE9?

Tags: crash, internet-explorer-9

There seems to be a [known bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3186922&group_id=188828&atid=926877) in AllChars 4.0.321 when used together with Internet Explorer 9 (my default browser).

While AllChars is running, I can't use Internet Explorer or open the manual from the AllChars menu. In both cases I get an error and a WerFault.exe process starts consuming a lot of CPU (about 50%).

I tried [these hints](http://www.ehow.com/how_5085062_stop-werfaultexe.html) to disable starting WerFault.exe, but it didn't help.

Any ideas how I can use this tool in a safe way?

Comment: If you have an american keyboard, I would suggest to give JLG utility (http://www.jlg-utilities.com/) a try ... Not open source and not very customizable, not a perfect compose key replacement, but still more characters supported than AllChars, and above all, much more stable ...